# MapView black screen

Tags: android

I have problem with MapView I got my Map Api key and you paste it into code, when I installed my aplication on emulator it shows black screen and information in LogCat: Couldn't get connection factory clien. 
Anybody can help ?
I would be thankfull

Comment: Couldn't get connection factory client is normal for me.  Debug / release key missmatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you generate a api key from one pc it will work in that pc only

If you get that error means, you didnt given correct api key or try to give uses permissions in `manifest.xml`

Access coarse location, access fine location and internet permission

In the application tag add uses library as this